# Setting a password for a zip file

Tags: .net-core, zip

I'm trying to set a password for a zip file using [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) library with .Net Core.

I have followed [this](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples) example in order to set a password, however once the zip file has been created, the files are in there and the zip file is create, however there is no password.

```
// Create a password for the Zipfolder
// https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples
using (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile ZipFile = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile(Path.GetFileName(destinationPath)))
{
     ZipFile.Password = "foo";
     ZipFile.Add(destinationPath, "");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers worked for me,
With that being said I found [this](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FastZip) Fast Zip class within the SharpZipLib library that has worked for me.

```
// Create a password for the Zipfolder
// https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip zipFile = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip();
zipFile.Password = "foo";
zipFile.CreateEmptyDirectories = true;
zipFile.CreateZip(destinationPath,tempPath, true, "");
```

The only thing I don't like about it however is that is doesn't implement [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

Answer (score 2):

I used the Example from the wiki and it worked without a Problem.

Code:

```
using (FileStream fsOut = File.Create(@"d:\temp\sharplib_pwtest.zip"))
using (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(fsOut)) {
    zipStream.SetLevel(3);
    zipStream.Password = "Testpassword";
    var folderName = @"D:\temp\sharpZipLibTest\";
    int folderOffset = folderName.Length + (folderName.EndsWith("\\") ? 0 : 1);
    CompressFolder(folderName, zipStream, folderOffset);
}
```

Comment: Gave this a try and still no password.

Comment: Did you try to extract the zip file? He does not ask for it when you open the zip file, so filenames are readable

Comment: @Lord_Pinhead zip file lists are always visible even when they are pw protected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for y'all help. I took @traveler3668 answer and added a little bit more details. I used paths from my project as an example.

This worked for me:

```
using System.Web.Security; //to generate password
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

string password = Membership.GeneratePassword(32, 10);
var zip = new FastZip();
zip.Password = password;
zip.CreateZip(
"C:\\dev\\InterfaceStatus\\InterfaceStatus\\App_Data\\test-folder_31-10-2022_11-23-54.zip", 
"C:\\dev\\InterfaceStatus\\InterfaceStatus\\App_Data\\test-folder_31-10-2022_11-23-54", 
true, 
""
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `BeginUpdate()` and `CommitUpdate()` and that will reflect in your output.

```
using (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile ZipFile = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile(Path.GetFileName(destinationPath)))
{
    ZipFile.BeginUpdate();
    ZipFile.Password = "foo";
    ZipFile.Add(destinationPath, "");
    ZipFile.CommitUpdate();
}
```

Comment: you tested this yeah? appears that no password is present.